# Differentiability at endpoints of curves

Tags: calculus, integration

This might sound like a silly question, but, why is it that for many theorems requiring a function be continuous on a curve on $[a,b]$, that whether the endpoints are differentiable don't matter?
For example, the Mean Value Theorem requires that for a continuous function $f$ on $[a,b]$, it must be differentiable on $(a,b)$. Why is the interval open instead of closed now?

Comment: Why *should* the endpoints matter? Think about $\sqrt x$ on $[0,1]$; surely the mean value theorem holds there even though a derivative at $0$ can't be meaningfully defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, those types of assumptions are based on what's minimally required for the theorem to be true, and just those bare minimum requirements.

In the example you give, the MVT doesn't hold generally if $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ - think about what happens if there's a jump discontinuity at one of the endpoints. So, we need continuity on the closed interval or the theorem can be violated.

Similarly, the MVT is true when $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$. Requiring differentiability on $[a,b]$ instead would be a stricter requirement, and would needlessly limit the scope of the theorem. It would no longer apply to any functions that are not differentiable at either endpoint, even though the conclusion of the theorem would still be true for them.